# Calculate angle of triangle with sin or cos

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, angle, trigonometry

I'm trying to calculate an angle based on triangle sides, preferably with sin.
The first 2 are helper functions `getDistance` and `getPointsDifference`

I have these functions:

```
var getDistance = function(p1, p2){
    var dx = p1.x - p2.x, dy = p1.y - p2.y;
    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}

var getPointsDifference = function(p1, p2){

    return {
        x: -1 * (p1.x - p2.x),
        y: (p1.y - p2.y)
    }
}
```

and finaly:

```
var getMenuChoice = function(cx,cy, x, y){

    var distance = getDistance({x:cx,y:cy}, {x:x,y:y});

    if (distance <= 100) {
        console.log(1)
    } else {
        console.log(2)
    }

    var diff = getPointsDifference({x:cx,y:cy}, {x:x,y:y});
    var a = Math.sin(diff.y/distance)

    console.log("asdf:", a)

}
```

Could someone please show me what am I doing wrong? I would like to calculate the result in degrees.

**update**

I detect a lick on the screen which gives me a x,y, and then I subtract those x,y from cx and cy which are the center of the screen

Comment: How do you define triangle? By its vertices?

Comment: There's no triangle in your code, only two points, a triangle contains three points ...

Comment: @Syd `I detect a lick on the screen which gives me a x,y, and then I subtract those x,y from cx and cy which are the center of the screen` how is this related to triangle?

Comment: isn't there a virtual triangle once you have a center and an other point ? if you project x and y on the corresponding axis?

Comment: @Syd do you want to find the angle (direction) of the vector from the point of click to the center of the screen?

Comment: Yes, but you didn't say that in the post.

Comment: Sorry for any confussion my goal is to get an angle between 0 and 360 degrees having only the center and a click event, each of them have an x and a y.

Comment: [`Math.atan2()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2) gives you an angle related to X-axis in radians. Converting to degrees should be a trivial task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called the angle (or direction) of the vector from (or to, depends on what you need) point of click to the center of the screen. There is no need in calculation of the distance and arcsin of the angle (instead of yours sin) - you can just use `Math.atan2(dy, dx);`.

`dy` is change in y (y2 - y1) and `dx` is change in x (x2 - x1) between those two points. You can use a regular `Math.atan(dy / dx)`, but then you must be sure that you are not dividing by zero and have to take into account the signs of dy and dx to have answer in the correct quadrant. `Math.atan2` will do it all for you. And the picture below is just a reminder.

[image]

And yes, the answer will be in radians, as it was mentioned in comments. Conversion is simple `degrees = radians * (180 / Math.PI);`